# retrive string from txt file to vector of int C++ using void methods

Tags: c++

Hello guys I'am trying to insert numbers form text file into a vector of int 
the text file called "graphe.txt" its content like : 
enter image description here

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <vector>

#include <string>

#include <sstream>

#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


void load(ifstream & inputFile, vector < int > G) {

    string currentLine;


    if (inputFile.is_open()) //Always test the file open.
    {
        while (getline(inputFile, currentLine)) {
            if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                int s = stoi(currentLine);
                G.push_back(s);
            }

        }
        inputFile.close();
    } else
        cout << "file is not open" << '\n';
}

void shwTab(vector < int > G) {
    vector < int > ::iterator it;
    for (it = G.begin(); it != G.end(); ++it)
        cout << * it << " \n";
    cout << endl;
}


int main() {
    ifstream inputFile("graphe.txt");
    vector < int > G;
    load(inputFile, G);
    shwTab(G);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is like :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wx03.png

I dont know exactly where the problem is ? the numbers doesnt appear !

Comment: You should pass the reference to your vector `G` so that you get it populated by `load()` function. In your solution `load()` function modifies the **copy** of `G`. I.e. signature should be `void load(ifstream& inputFile, vector<int> &G )` instead.

Comment: Don't post images here. Also you passed the vector by copy, so the function filled its own local vector

Comment: @vahancho thank you it worked.

Comment: @Quimby why I cant post images ? there is an icon to insert images in the discription field !!

Comment: @DjoSafi Posting an image of something that's just text is poor style here -- even more so when it's a link you have to click and not displayed inline.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `vector<int> G` as reference, in your example a copy of `G` is passed to `load`.

```
void load(ifstream& inputFile,vector<int> &G)
```

Notice the **&** before `G`.

Not that relevant, but you could do the same for the `shwTab` function:

```
void shwTab (vector<int> &G)
```

to avoid copying the entire vector. It's not necessary, but you do save some memory.